# Post ID into plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a small plugin to update the acf fields in a posts. In each post, there are many fields that need to be updated with the received data from the API. In the code below, I first demonstrate from one api I get the code I need, then using foreach I get the data for each post. Now I need to update the fields. I have collected all acf keys into one array and I want to use switch to update the fields. But, I ran into a problem that I cannot get the post id in the plugin. What's the correct way to do this?

**plugin.php**

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'cr_api_tools_api');

function cr_api_tools_api() {
    add_menu_page( 'CP API Tools', 'CP API', 'manage_options', 'cr-api-tools-plugin', 'cr_api_tools_init');
    function cr_api_tools_view() {
        wp_register_style('cr-api-tools-view', plugins_url('/view/cr-api-tools-view.css',__FILE__ ), array(), time());
        wp_enqueue_style('cr-api-tools-view');
    }
    add_action( 'admin_init','cr_api_tools_view');
}

function cr_api_tools_init () { ?>

    <div class="container">
        <form method="post" class="cr-api-tools">
            <h1>CP API TOOLS</h1>
            <input type="submit" name="enable" class="enable" value="Enable">
        </div>

        <?php 
        if( isset( $_POST['enable'] ) ) {


            global $post;
            $postID = $post->ID;

        // JOB API
            $url='api/url';
            $result     = file_get_contents( $url );
            $result_data = json_decode( $result );

            foreach ($result_data as  $job) {

                $ref_code = $job->RefCode;
                $post_title = $job->JobTitle;



                $post_id    = post_exists( $post_title );

                if( !$post_id ){
                    $data = array(
                        'post_type'   => 'post',
                        'post_title'  => $post_title,
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'post_author' => $user_ID,
                    );
                    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $data );
                }
                
            // Job DATA API
                $job_api_url ='api/url' . $ref_code;
                $job_api_result = file_get_contents( $job_api_url );
                $result_api_data = json_decode( $job_api_result );


                $acf_keys = [ 
                    'location', 
                    'job_intro', 
                    'job_offer'
                ];                      

                if(is_array($acf_keys)) {
                    foreach ($acf_keys as $value) {
                        switch ($value) {
                            case 'location':
                            update_field( $value, $job->Region, $postID );
                            break;
                            case 'job_intro':
                            update_field( $value, $job->JobTitle, $postID );
                            break;
                            case 'job_offer':
                            update_field( $value, $job->Description, $postID );
                            break;
                            default:
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }

        ?>



    </form>     
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: When is this code running? If it is running too early, the global post won't have been set up yet.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I don't fully understand your answer, do I need to add global $ post inside the loop?

Comment: Take a look at this [list of Wordpress actions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)... this is the order that the actions run when WP is loading.  The global `$post` isn't reliably available until the `wp` action. If your code i running before that (e.g. when the plugin is loaded in the `plugins_loaded` action near the beginning), then the global post hasn't been loaded yet. You need to make sure you are hooking this function into an action that executes *after* wp

Comment: I don’t get why you are trying to use `add_menu_page` here in the first place? That calls your function, when you go to the corresponding menu page in the backend. How do you expect to get a connection to one single, specific post ID from there?

Comment: @CBroe And how can I do it right so that the user can enter the plugin, click on enable and my plugin code works?

Comment: @CBroe add full code

Comment: You could start by giving a _proper_ description of what you need to achieve here. You say you need to update fields “in a post” - what post? Selected how?

Comment: @CBroe Initially, I have no posts. I get data from api and insert posts by title. In these created posts there are fields that I have to update with the received data from the api and for this I need the id of those created posts

Comment: _“I get data from api and insert posts by title”_ - so use the post ID you got back from that insert operation then? You did already capture that with `$post_id = wp_insert_post( $data );`, so where is the problem, why even think about using any `global $post` now?

Comment: @CBroe Can you write a piece of code? I'm confused (

Comment: `update_field( $value, $job->Region, $postID );` –> `update_field( $value, $job->Region, $post_id );` …!?!

Comment: @CBroe Thank you very much !! this is my carelessness, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @CBroe Please add this as the correct answer so that I can check a green marker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t want to get a specific, global post ID here - you are not in a context where that would make sense to begin with (like the frontend view for a specific post, or the edit view in the backend.)

```
            $post_id    = post_exists( $post_title );

            if( !$post_id ){
                // ...
                $post_id = wp_insert_post( $data );
            }
```

Here you are getting the ID of the already existing post, resp. that of the newly created one.

So that is the ID you want to use afterwards, to update additional meta data of that particular post. These

```
update_field( $value, $job->Region, $postID );
```

calls need to become

```
update_field( $value, $job->Region, $post_id );
```

And the following can be removed completely, not necessary or useful in this context:

```
        global $post;
        $postID = $post->ID;
```